# What determines the speed of an SVN 1.6 merge operation

Tags: performance, svn, merge

I am surprised at how long it takes to merge a very small change from any particular branch into trunk; 1-2 minutes to merge in a few lines of text that have changed in a single text file that is only 2k long.

I would like, if possible, to make merging a hell of a lot faster but don't know where to start.  I have done a quick google and the possible reasons for slow merges seem to include any and all of the following: -

- Large repo size (both in terms of size on disk and number of revisions).
- Large source tree (apparently SVN has to crawl down the tree in order to work out changes)
- The version of SVN server / client
- Very large (several MB) files (we don't have very large single files so I doubt this affect us)

I guess I really want to know how to find out which of the above points are making merges so slow.

Right now I am in the dark as to whether it is work on the client or work on the server that is taking the most time (well I suspect it is the client since CPU usage is not massive on the server).  I did think that it might be the vast amount of mergeinfo that has accumulated over 100s of merges but I have done a test where I have deleted all the merge info from a couple of branch and then did a merge and found the same slowness.

So what I would like to ask is: -
* How would one go about diagnosing/profiling the SVN activity?
* Based on the info below, is there something really obvious that will be causing the poor performance?

Thanks

Chris

**Here are some facts / figures about our SVN setup**

- Our SVN repository has around 32000 revisions.
- Repo size on disk: 8.3GB
- Our development branches each have around 1400 versioned folders (19,000 versioned files)
- SVN Server: 1.6.6 (r40053) (hosted in Apache running on Ubunto Lucid Lynx)
- I am using tortoise 1.6.9 on Win7 (although other members of the team use SmartSVN and they report the same sort of speed).

*Edit*

It might be worth adding that when we branch / merge, we branch from trunk and always merge the entire branch back into trunk.  So all the mergeinfo is on the trunk (and branches) folder.

**Conclusions**

In my case, it appeared to be the disk access that was the bottleneck in the merge process - when I moved my source tree from my HDD to my SSD, the same merge went from 50 +/- 5s to 7 +/- 1s.
Watching the tortoise SVN process in process explorer during the merge was quite telling: whilst doing a merge on my HDD the I/O bytes was between 500kb/s and 3Mb/s for most of the duration.  On the SSD the I/O bytes was up to 10-20Mb/s.   [Rather confusingly, some merges on my HDD were of comparable speed (and I/O bytes were similarly high) as those on my SSD - in these cases, I assume that a lot of the files being read were already in the windows file cache].

I found the following all increased merge speed

- Merging from & to a folder deeper down the source hierarchy: this is not really an option for us to in "real-life" because merge tracking becomes almost impossible if not recorded at the "trunk-level" folder but does show that merging much smaller trees makes the process much faster.
- Reducing the size of the working set being merged to helps (provided that you use the "working set" depth merge option and not the fully recursive) - so by simply deleting the folders (from my working set under trunk) increased speed.

Comment: `5.00MB transferred in 29 minutes and 32 seconds` .... so yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try merge in a shorter tree to find if it returns quicker to see if the smaller tree makes a difference.

Note: There has been a lot of merge related improvements in the latest version check the below link

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.11/CHANGES

Upgrading to latest might help.

Comment: It appears to be the disk access that takes most of the time with my merge so merging smaller trees are quicker - see comments end of my question

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed while merging is that merges that use top level directory are very fast. So that merging a feature branch back to trunk or merging a range of revision from trunk to your feature branch is fast. But merging changes from a specific file somewhere in the working copy is extremely slow. For this reason I always branch the entire trunk and then change whatever files I need to, then merge the entire thing. So if your branch was created from one trunk's subdirectory this might be why it's very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nikola.  We too follow your pattern of branching / merging (i.e. always branch from of trunk folder and not a sub folder)

Answer (score 0):

Another factor is the relative delta between the two branches. So for example, if you branch off of trunk and then merge trunk into the branch a month later, this will take a long time, relatively speaking. On the other hand, if you merge from trunk into your branch every day, this will be relatively fast.